# Vim the yb copy

Tags: vim

When I use **yb** to copy backwards,it does not copy the character under the cursor.
( **yiw** can sometimes solve the problem,but not always. For example when copying backwards to a mark)

Are there any simple ways to copy backwards in vim which copying the character under the cursor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with a backwards `b` motion, the character under the cursor is not included; [`:help b`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#b) mentions that this is an *exclusive* motion. You can use [`:help o_v`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#o_v):

> If the motion already was characterwise, toggle
>   inclusive/exclusive.  This can be used to make an exclusive
>   motion inclusive and an inclusive motion exclusive.

So just do `yvb`. Alternatively, if you have the (default) `:set selection=inclusive`, you could also go into visual mode to solve this: `vby`.

Comment: Thank you so much! **yvb** helps a lot! It also works when copying to a mark!